# getting white lines on left side Android screen wherever white buttons

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, lottie

I'm getting white lines on some android devices.
Background screen is black but wherever some buttons or lottie animation, this line gets visible as vertical line of 2/3px, to the left part of the screen.
Shared screenshot below:

In some devices, right part of ui gets visible in left part as vertical line of 2/3px.

There is no information on internet around it, Is there any solution/workaround for these?

[image]

Comment: Any source code or context? Please provide context, code and minimal repro

Comment: Layout has Constrainlayout match_parent with fullscreen lottie and recyclerview grid. One gets visible at a time. These white lines are not getting reproduced in some devices, randomly coming on some.

Comment: Do you use special fonts on the text of those bubbles?

Comment: I used "degular" fonts for all texts

Answer (score 0):

as there is no sample code i would look into these places:

1. the image itself may have a background and not fully transparent
2. check the xml file for items of recyclerview if there is a paddingRight or some sort of margin with white background

3.check for cardview elevation

Answer (score 0):

Once I faced the same issue caused by the layout holding a button or an image view. The layout's background color was different from its parent layout, & I had to declare that layout to keep my Views & alignments. The solution to that problem was to add this attribute:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

And why isn't there any source code?